# Is it possible to change the Header of a get-request of an npm module? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, npm, get, http-headers, spoofing

I'm using an npm module which makes an api request:

`const api_req = require('my-npm-module-that-makes-an-api-request');`

However, I need to change the `user-agent` of the request that is submitted internally by the npm module - can I do this without modifying the module itself, i.e. is there a way to say (for example), that all get requests in my code should be made with header X, without modifying the actual lines of code in the npm modules that make requests? Or is there another way to spoof my user agent?

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {get: () => 'Your UA here'});
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! can you explain this a bit more? will this work in my 'parent code' and apply to all API calls? I'm not sure I totally understand, but looks promising! Also: what is `navigator`? thanks again!!

Comment: @R.Kohlisch, `navigator` or `window.navigator` is a property retrieving [`Navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) interface.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working in node, I guess I won't have `window.navigator`. What could I put instead?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch, sorry for the confusion. In your question you did not mention that you use `node`. I thought it was in browser. Server-side is a different story. Which module do you use?

Comment: Thanks so much for understanding, and sorry for not having clarified this straightaway. I'm a beginner so I'm sometimes not sure. I am trying to use the npm module `google-translate-api` [(github link)](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api/blob/master/index.js) on my raspberry pi. My full node.js code can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618447/google-translate-api-rejects-exact-same-script-executed-on-raspberry-pi-but-acc) - I thought spoofing the user-agent might help me out, but it's just a guess, so that's why I'm asking the current question.